# Rational approximation of transcendental and algebraic numbers

Tags: soft-question, real-numbers

I had a discussion with a friend that say that

> transcendental numbers can be better approximated by rationals than
>   algebraic (irrational) numbers, so, is some sense, they are more
>   ''near'' to rationals that the algebraic numbers.

I don't understand in what sense this statement can be true (and I suspect that it is false).

I know that the way to estimate how a irrational number is approximated by rational is the irrationality measure, and that this measure is $1$ for rational numbers, $2$ for algebraic numbers, $\ge 2$ for transcendental numbers and $\infty$ for Liouville numbers.

I interpret this as the Liouville numbers are the numbers better approximated by rationals (correct?) and we know that these numbers are transcendental. But I also know that the set of Liouville numbers has measure $0$, so almost all transcendental numbers have irrationality measure $\ge 2$ but $< \infty$.  But we cannot prove that almost all have irrationality measure $>2$, so we cannot say that thay are generally better approximated by rationals. Or there is some proof?

Anyway, i think that the idea of ''near to'' cannot be applied in this situation since it is obviously false in standard topology of reals and I don't see a topology in which it can be true. Or there is someone?

Comment: you want thue-roth-siegel to begin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Siegel%E2%80%93Roth_theorem  I can also recommend http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/number-theory/neverending-fractions-introduction-continued-fractions which is inexpensive

Comment: my first observation is that your friend may have meant the subset of transcendentals called https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number  and the problem is that he appeared to be talking about all transcendentals

Comment: I see, read the middle part, you already know Liouville numbers.

Comment: @WillJagy: so the statement is true for *all* the Liouville numbers but is false for *almost all* transcendental numbers ( as I suppose)?

Comment: In fact, almost all numbers have irrationality measure of 2, so that's right, they are as good (or as bad) as algebraic.

Comment: Emilio, "The Liouville numbers are precisely those numbers having infinite irrationality measure." Other than that, I suspect you know as much, or more, than I do. I do recommend the Neverending book, Zudilin is rather a star in this area.

Comment: @IvanNeretin:  Please, can you say me where I can found a proof of the fact that almost all irrational have irrationality measure $2$?

Comment: Probably by a reference from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Irrationality_measure)?

Comment: @IvanNeretin, it's in the Bugeaud book, I posted an answer. The book is not primarily about continued fractions, can't win 'em all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proof is given in Bugeaud, Yann (2012). [Distribution modulo one and Diophantine approximation](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/number-theory/distribution-modulo-one-and-diophantine-approximation?format=HB). Cambridge Tracts in Mathematics 193. With theorem statement on page 246 and proof reaching page 247. Naturally, page 246 is not part of the online preview. The really good pages never are. It seems it is in Appendix E.

[image]

Comment: I found this answer quite misleading and would recommend editing it to state exactly what is being proved. The OP said "we cannot prove that almost all [transcendental numbers] have irrationality measure > 2 ... Or there is some proof?" This book except appears to prove the opposite claim: that almost all transcendental numbers have irrationality measure *equal* to 2.

Answer (score 2):

A quadratic irrational $x$ has an eventually periodic continued fraction, and therefore a continued fraction with bounded terms.  That in turn
implies that $x$ can't have very good rational approximations: there is 
$c > 0$ such that $|x - p/q| > c/q^2$ for every rational $p/q$.  On the other hand, almost all $x$ have unbounded terms, so there are $p/q$ with
$q^2 |x - p/q| $ arbitrarily small.

Unfortunately, we know very little about the continued fractions for algebraic numbers of degree $>2$; AFAIK the betting is that they have
unbounded terms.